# com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {'code': 400}

Tags: azure

[here is the picture of the code and error occured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hXGn.png)
please help me with this the data insertion in azure exception occurs as follows

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:

com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: {'code': 400}

Comment: Could you please share your error code with us for further research?

Comment: right now i wanted to offline sync the database table so , i created a sqlite database and in the data is read from sqlite database and after that the data is pushed into the azure database , when performing that action , i see an exception as above

Comment: @ LeeLiu .....i have solved the issue as i fixed into the data i am sending in the azure table, thankyou very much for your interest to help and i need to say that you are doing a good job ,thanks once again

Comment: You're welcome.